# jQuery dialog not firing, Update panel on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

```
<asp:Content ID="conBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphClientBody" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpnlRate" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            page code..............
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>  

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("<div title='Basic dialog'>Test message</div>").dialog();
    });
```

Is this not firing due to the update panel?
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Do you have a master page ? If so, should you not put your scripts to the head ContentPlaceHolder ?

Comment: Are you getting a client side error? Check your browser's F12 development tools, look at the console tab.

Comment: @mason yes. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: That means jQuery or jQuery UI probably didn't get loaded correctly. So go to the Network tab in your browser's dev tools, and see if there was an error downloading the `.js` files.

Comment: @mason They appear to have got loaded correctly. Could it be that multiple versions of jquery are called on the page?

Comment: You should never have more the one version of the jQuery core library on the page. You only need one. Pick one, and remove the reference to the other.

Comment: @mason old page that has been edited by numerous people! Still getting the same client side error once all other references were removed

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Start with just a basic page (no master page) and try to get a basic dialog working. Then start adding stuff until it does everything you want. Add one thing at a time, so that you'll know which thing it is that breaks your code. That should help you identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this all the time. 
        $(document).ready(function () {})
only runs once with update panels.

Switch to 
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {}

Comment: Your dialog declaration doesn't look quite right
Shouldn't it be more like 
$('#dlgName').dialog({})